# Unable to load dynamic library Error showing up with phpbb forum?

Tags: php, apache, forum, phpbb

i've a forum and i've installed phpbb3 and i happened to see my forum is not showing anything..

I've uploaded a test file and phpinfo() function and all is working fine but all others are not working..

the error log shows

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
'/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/http.so' 
- /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/http.so: cannot open shared
object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

but could not what the error might be..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a line in php.ini that includes a PHP extension "http", however the shared library for this extension is missing. Edit the php.ini to correct the problem.

Comment: If the answer is not obvious for you, there are in your php.ini (probably on top) few `extension=` lines. The `http.so` has to be below `propro.so` and `raphf.so` according to [dependencies](http://devel-m6w6.rhcloud.com/mdref/http#Dependencies:). My `pecl install pecl_http` mixed it up and did it in incorrect order.

Answer (score 1):

Check your php.ini or your extensions.ini file (check your `php -i` or `phpinfo();` for locations) and make sure that `extension=http.so` is at the bottom of the file.